# Switching connect dynamically in Modellica.mechanics

Tags: dynamic, connect, modelica, dymola

I tried to simulate a "special" pendulum with the Modelica library.
The pendulum got one revolute at the first end and a secound revolute on the other end. At `time < t` the first pendulum should rotate around the axis of the first revolute. At `time > t` the pendulum should rotate around the axis of the secound revolute.
I have two problems:

1. I cannot simulate a pendulum with two revolutes where one frame ist unused.
2. I tried to change the rotating revolute by using an if-clause like this:
   `if time < 5 then 
   connect(world.frame_b, revolute.frame_a);
   else
   connect(world.frame_b, revolute1.frame_b);
   end if;`
   Starting the simulation I get this error:
   `Failed to expand block containing connect:
   if (time < 5) then 
   connect(world.frame_b, revolute.frame_a);
   else
   connect(world.frame_b, revolute1.frame_b);
   end if;`

Has Someone an Idea how i can solve this problems?

[modelpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXhmt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is pretty much related to the discussion found here:
[Switch between two flanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340160/switch-between-two-flanges)

Summary: You can not switch connects during simulation as this would require to rebuild the equations during simulation.

Regarding your problem: To be honest I don't see a sound way to solve the issue in Modelica.